Looking for an exhaustive list of legal statuses (for people) in halakha
Shalom.
Is there an exhaustive list of halakhic legal statuses (for people) available anywhere? I’ve come across more than one instance in my own life where I could not fathom my own halakhic legal status.
Many thanks for your time.

I know a great set that goes through them all - it's called Talmud Bavli :)

@Rabbi Kaii - :D Roger, point taken :) If you put ‘try the TB’ in an answer I will accept.

I could not fathom my own halakhic legal status. It's very unclear what you mean by that. "Jewish male adult" are three halachic statuses, but they're not mutually exclusive. You can be some of them, or all of them and more, depending on the context. If you're looking for a halachic "class" ranking, here's one from the Rambam. Otherwise, I think the question is too broad for a meaningful answer.

The Shulchan Aruch, Aruch Hashulchan or Mishneh Torah would contain most statuses, but for the total list, you'll need to finish Shas Bavli and Yerushalmi, I think! The list is huge, depending on how specific you want to get. Just to show how a extensive list it can be, is here an AI assisted* list, which is not exhaustive:

Patur (Exempt)
Chayav (Obligated)
Chayav Mita (Liable to Death Penalty)


Skila (Stoning)
Srefa (Burning)
Hereg (Beheading)
Chenek (Strangulation)
Bidei Shamayim (Die Young)
Karet (Spiritual Excision) V'Ariri (Unusual/Childless Death)


Chayav Malkot (Liable to Lashes)
Chayav Korban (Obligated to Bring a Sacrifice)
Mamzer (Child Born from Certain Forbidden Relationships)
Eved Ivri (Hebrew Slave)
Eved Canaani (Canaanite Slave)
Yisrael (Israelite)
Kohen (Priest)
Levi (Levite)
Kohen Gadol (High Priest)
Ger (Convert to Judaism)
Ger Toshav (Resident Alien)
Nazir (Nazirite)
Metzora (Person with Biblical Leprosy)
Zav (Male with Certain Bodily Discharges)
Zavah (Female with Abnormal Discharges)
Niddah (Menstruant Woman)
Onen (Immediate Mourner Before Burial)
Avel (Mourner After Burial)
Cheresh (Deaf-Mute)
Shoteh (Mentally Incompetent Person)
Katan (Minor)
Gadol (Adult)
Petzu'a Daka (Man with Crushed Testicles)
Sris Chama (Naturally Sterile Man)
Sris Adam (Man Made Sterile by Human Action)
Ailonit (Woman Who Does Not Develop Signs of Puberty)
Tumtum (Person with Indeterminate Sex)
Androgynos (Person with Both Male and Female Characteristics)
Chalal (Disqualified Kohen)
Gerusha (Divorcee)
Chalutzah (Woman Released from Levirate Marriage)
Yevamah (Levirate Widow)
Yavam (Levirate Brother-in-Law)
Ben Noach (Noahide, Non-Jew Observing Noahide Laws)
Apikores (Heretic)
Meshumad (Apostate)
Am Ha'aretz (Unlearned Person)
Dayan (Judge)
Ed (Witness)
Gazlan (Robber)
Ganav (Thief)
Rodef (Pursuer with Intent to Kill)
Nirdaf (One Being Pursued)
Ben Sorer U'Moreh (Rebellious Son)
Zaken Mamre (Rebellious Elder)
Sotah (Woman Suspected of Adultery)
Eishes Ish (Married Woman)
Penuyah (Unmarried Woman)
Goses (Person Near Death)
Mumar L'teavon (One Who Sins Out of Desire)
Mumar Lehachis (One Who Sins to Anger God)
Chaver (Member of Learned Society)
Am Ha'aretz (Common Person)
Shomer Chinam (Unpaid Guardian)
Shomer Sachar (Paid Guardian)
Sho'el (Borrower)
Socher (Renter)
To'en (Plaintiff)
Nit'an (Defendant)
Malveh (Lender)
Loveh (Borrower)
Arev (Guarantor)
Pikadon (Depositor)
Meisir (Informer)
Mosser (One Who Betrays Fellow Jews to Authorities)
Mekubal (Recipient of Tradition)
Mohel (Circumciser)
Sandek (Holds Baby at a Circumcision)
Ba'al Brit (Father at a Circumcision)
Chatan (Groom)
Kallah (Bride)
Yatom (Orphan)
Ger Katan (Minor Convert)
Bechor (Firstborn)
Peti (Simpleton)
Kuti (Samaritan)
Nochri (Gentile)
Akum (Idol Worshiper)
Min (Heretic)
Tzeduki (Sadducee)
Moser (Informer)
Chashud (Suspected Person)
Tamei (Ritually Impure)
Tahor (Ritually Pure)
Ba'al Keri (Man with Seminal Emission)
Areil (Uncircumcised Male)
Mul (Circumcised Male)
Baal Mum (Person with Physical Blemish)
Choleh (Sick Person)
Choleh Sheyesh Bo Sakana (Dangerously Ill Person)
Choleh She'ain Bo Sakana (Non-Dangerously Ill Person)
Chaya (Woman in Childbirth)
Shomeret Yom K'neged Yom (Woman Counting Purity Days)
Mesarev Beit Din (One Who Refuses Court Orders)
Menudeh (Excommunicated Person)
Machzir Gerushato (One Who Remarries His Divorcee After Her Second Marriage)
Megadef (Blasphemer)
Mechashefa (Witch)
Ba'al Ov / Yid'oni (Type of Avodah Zarah)
Mekadesh (One Who Betroths a Woman)
Megarish (One Who Divorces His Wife)
Mefatem (Seducer)
Me'anes (Rapist)
Shochet (Ritual Slaughterer)
Sofer (Scribe)
Gabai (Community Official)
Shaliach Tzibbur (Prayer Leader)
Baal Kriah (Torah Reader)
Dayan (Judge)
Av Beit Din (Head of Rabbinical Court)
Meshamesh BeKodesh (One Who Serves in Holy Matters)
Osek BeMitzvah (Someone Currently Engaged in a Commandment)
Tinok SheNishba (Captive Child Unaware of Judaism)
Agunah (Woman Awaiting Husband's Status)
Mesarev Get (Refuser of Divorce)
Baal Lashon Hara (Habitual Slanderer)
Machti Harabim (One Who Leads the Public to Sin)
Kohen Tamei (Defiled Priest)
Kohen Hedyot (Ordinary Priest)
Ba'al Chov (Debtor)
Malveh (Creditor)
Shutaf (Partner)
Yorshim (Heirs)
Pasul Witness (Invalid Witness)
Nogea B'davar (Interested Party)
Ed Echad (Single Witness)
Modeh B'miktzat (Partial Admission)
Kofeir Hakol (Complete Denial)
Modi'in (Informer)
Baki (Expert)
Hedyot (Layperson)
Chashud Al Hashviit (Suspected of Violating Sabbatical Laws)
Chashud Al Hamaasrot (Suspected of Not Tithing)
Chaver (Trusted in Tithing)
Damai Dealer (Seller of Doubtfully Titled Produce)
Makpid (Strict Person)
Chassid (Pious Person)
Shaliach (Agent)
Ore'ach (Guest)
Rotzeach B'Shogeg (Inadvertent Murderer)
Rotzeach B'Mezid (Intentional Murderer)
Tinok Ben Yomo (Newborn Child)

* I made my own list, then fed it to ChatGPT, asked it to increase it, and then I vetted its list.

This is amazing! The mishnah also lists Challalim and natin (Gibeonite), Egyptian, Ammonite and Moabite converts

@יהושעק we could consider making this into a community post?

HaRav Kai, you did the real legwork here, I don't think there are even 10 more out there

@יהושעק wanna bet?! I bet you there're dozens more, if not hundreds

There could be more entries, like rotzeyach b'ones, also different levels of tahara for eatinng ma'aser, teruma, kodashim; 5 levels of rabbinic tum'ah; it would be good to group avos hatuma together (like meis,  metzorah, niddah, zav, zava, etc.), also different levels of kedusha (basically 1st perek of mishna Kelim)

@YDJ royal: Melech, Nasi, Kohen Mashuach Milchama, Reish Galuta. Legal: eid zomem, mesaye'a, chiyuv shevu'ah, and tons more. Financial: Arev Kablan, apotiki, shomer aveida, ani, ashir and many more. More from nashim, from tahara, from kodshim, zeraim (poel, sachir, chamar). Some from hilchot milchama, like chayal, pachadim. The differnet types of oath, noder, shavu'a. Quite a few diabilities left out like chiger, suma etc, and so many more, shikor, tzaddik, community roles like melamed, shamash etc

@RabbiKaii great job; I didn't even read this but it should be saved somewhere for reference of the correct way to use AI

@RabbiKaii I was referring to avot rather than toldot, but the amazing community here has taken this in a whole different direction!

Also differentiate between malkos 40 and malkos derabanan; t'reifa. Probably some more, but none I can think of. Great job!

Egyptian and Edomite can also be divided into first and second generation

There could literally be thousands more. The only purpose this answer serves, being so far from comprehensive, is showing how impossible to answer comprehensively this question is.

Each volume/edition also tends to have a sponsor!

68 and 84 are the same

What about karkafta d'lo monach tefillin

What's a meisier and a modi'in and how are they different from a mosser? What about a meisis? Also, I think mefatem should be mefateh. Anyway, most of these aren't halachic statuses, just descriptors. If you're going to list every term applied to any person, this should be a lot longer. I'm tempted to downvote, but maybe such a vague question deserves such an amorphous answer.

deputy kohen, war kohen,  a met (dead person), a moshiach, an istonis (fussy person), navi (prophet), false prophet, corner dweller (the ancient version of a mi yodeah forum user who can substitute for a rabbi on a beit din of 2 ignoramuses when nobody better is available)

sailors, camel drivers, donkey drivers, men of leisure - from that section on how frequently men whose professions keep them away from home must service their wives.

teachers of small children/older children - there is a gemara on whether they are liable for a mistake in their teachings. teacher of small children are, teacher of children who should be smart enough to catch it are not.

@DoubleAA that's literally what I wrote in the opening statement. Shmosel, most of these are halachic catagories i.e. there are halachos that apply to them. A few slipped in that aren't. And yes, given that this is an amorphous answer, I didn't spend hours on it and don't think I will edit it further, even though a few mistakes have been pointed out
